# Xamarin Grid UWP and iOS display issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a UI problem in Xamarin. It looks perfect in Android, but didn't work in iOS. I checked in UWP just to be sure, and it doesn't work there either. Now keep in mind the only reason I keep UWP project in there is for quick testing. I am not targeting UWP.

Here is the correct behavior in Android

[image]

Here is in the incorrect behavior in iOS ( I know that's a UWP screenshot, but its the same problem )

[image]

Here is the code XML, I can't figure this out to save my life.

```
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="16,40,16,0" Spacing="10">
                    <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" 
                          HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="128"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image x:Name="PhotoImageFront"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Source="camera_front.png" 
                           HeightRequest="128" />

                        <BoxView
                            Grid.Column="1"/>

                        <Image x:Name="PhotoImageRear"
                           Grid.Column="2"
                           Source="camera_rear.png" 
                           HeightRequest="128" />
                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Does `camera_front.png` exist in your iOS project?

Comment: I feel so stupid, but that was the problem... I had the file with a dash instead of an underscore.

Comment: The xaml looks correct, from above comments, you have found the problem that use wrong image file name, please feel free post your answer below and mark yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I had to rename my files from having dashes to underscores because of filename conventions in one of those projects. Somehow I missed a couple of renames. I had been battling this problem for hours, amazingly SushiHangover pointed me in the right direction 5 minutes after I posted the questions. Thanks guys!